# event.preventDefault() is not preventing the page from refreshing, i am using brave browser

Tags: javascript, html, events, refresh

everytime i click the submit button, the data gets added to the json server, but the page gets refreshed, and i dont want that to happen. why is prevent default not working? how can i prevent the page from refreshing?

```
let form = document.getElementById("addBooksForm").addEventListener("submit",getBooksData);
let tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");

let bookDetails = {};

function getBooksData(event){
    
    event.preventDefault()
    
    let coverUrl = document.getElementById("url").value;
    let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    let author = document.getElementById("author").value;
    let genre = document.getElementById("genre").value;
    let edition = document.getElementById("edition").value;
    let publisher = document.getElementById("publisher").value;
    let price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    
    bookDetails = {
        coverUrl,
        name,
        author,
        genre,
        edition,
        publisher,
        price,
        borrowed: false
    };

    
    addBooks(bookDetails);
    fetchBooks();
}

async function addBooks(bookDetails){

     try{
        let res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/books`,{
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(bookDetails),
            headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
        });
        let data = await res.json();
        console.log(data)
     }catch(err){

     }
}
```

Comment: could you add your html code ?

Comment: `preventDefault` is the correct way to do this, and you seem to be setting up the `submit` handler correctly, so the problem is something subtle, most likely in code you haven't shown. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). (You can use forms in Stack Snippets provided you do what you're doing: prevent form submission.)

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/8jr097ne/).

Comment: When you load the page is there any error messages in the console? What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not directly tackling your preventDefault problem, but I suggest a replacement to that dreaded and out of control "async/await" combo!

Try this logical and manageable alternative format to fetch things...

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/books',{

            method: "POST",

            body: JSON.stringify(bookDetails),

            headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"}

          }).then(resp => resp.json()).then(function(data){

 // process "data" here as needed

});
```